Emit static with relocation of type `R_MIPS_16`
I'm currently compiling some rust code against the mipsel-sony-psx target, which has 32-bit pointers. I have two statics that I need to emit with a specific size (4 bytes and 2 bytes, respectively):
use core::ptr;

static mut EXT_DATA_ALL: *const u8 = ptr::addr_of!(EXT_DATA);
static mut EXT_DATA_LO: u16 = ptr::addr_of!(EXT_DATA) as u16; // Doesn't work

extern "C" {
    static mut EXT_DATA: u8;
}

The first static, EXT_DATA_ALL, works as-is, and emits a relocation of type R_MIPS_32. Ideally, I'd want it to be a u32, but rust doesn't let me cast at compile time despite the relocation not caring about the type of the variable, and the size and alignment of u32 and *const _ being the same, but I can live with that.
The second static, EXT_DATA_LO, however, doesn't work, and I'm not sure if I can make it work. I want it to contain the bottom 16 bits of the pointer. I believe the relocation R_MIPS_16 should work for this purpose, since it should truncate the address to 16 bits, but I have no clue how to get rust to emit it.
Error message:
error: pointers cannot be cast to integers during const eval
    --> ...
     |
     |     ptr::addr_of!(EXT_DATA) as u16,
     |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     |
     = note: at compile-time, pointers do not have an integer value
     = note: avoiding this restriction via `transmute`, `union`, or raw pointers leads to compile-time undefined behavior

I'd also be fine with adding the relocations outside of the rust code (for e.g., by editing the elf file to add my relocation later on), but I'm afraid the compiler could perform optimizations based on the dummy value I place in the variable (since I'd have to initialize it with something). Is this a valid concern, or is that my only way forward?
I believe that using global_asm!, I can define the relocation properly using .half %lo(EXT_DATA), but I need the data to reside in a rust static, and I don't think global_asm! can be used to declare statics.

Can you declare your relocation with global_asm (or with external assembly), then declare it to Rust in an extern block?

@Jmb I can't believe I hadn't thought of that, that's really simple, but unfortunately, it seems my assembler doesn't have a way to emit a 16-bit relocation for MIPS code. Using .half EXT_DATA results in "Error: cannot represent BFD_RELOC_16 relocation in this object file format", while .half %lo(EXT_DATA) results in a parser error since it seems %lo isn't allowed on .half declarations. I read about a BFD_RELOC_MIPS_16 relocation that was made for this, but I can't seem to emit it.
